# Should I buy this? vs Will I buy this?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

So I was shopping with my friends and found a nice shirt that I wanted to buy then asked my friend sayin “Will I buy this?”

So, my question is, is ‘Will’ able to be used in this kind of context? Or does ‘Should’ sound better?

I also want to ask you which sentence is the better one?

> Will I do this for you?
>   Should I do this for you?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the variety of English.

Some speakers of Scottish English say "Will I buy this?" perfectly normally.

Elsewhere that would be odd, unless asking for a prediction.

For me, and many (but not all) speakers in England, the normal form is "Shall I buy this?" But I don't think that is much used in the US.

"Should I buy this" is I think acceptable everywhere; but where other options are available, it might have a more restricted meaning. So for me, "Should I buy this?" suggests that I'm not as enthusiastic about it as if I said "Shall I buy this?"

Answer (score 6):

"Will I buy this?" is a rather odd question.  It asks for a fact about the future. You are asking your friend to predict what will happen. This is okay in some contexts:

> Will it rain today? / No, the forecast is for sunny weather.
>
> Will I pass the test? / Yes, but only if you study everyday.

There are other, rhetorical uses of will. But your question is not one of them. If you ask "Will I buy this?" my answer will be "I don't know! How can I predict what you will do!?"

If you want advice then "Should I buy this?" is better. But there are lots of other options: "What do you think of this?", "Does this suit me?" and so on.